# Least-Squares Regression of Matrices with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, regression, linear-regression

I'm looking to calculate least squares linear regression from an N by M matrix and a set of known, ground-truth solutions, in a N-1 matrix. From there, I'd like to get the slope, intercept, and residual value of each regression. Basic idea being, I know the actual value of that should be predicted for each sample in a row of N, and I'd like to determine which set of predicted values in a column of M is most accurate using the residuals.

I don't describe matrices well, so here's a drawing:

```
(N,M) matrix with predicted values for each row N
 in each column of M...

##NOTE: Values of M and N are not actually 4 and 3, just examples
   4 columns in "M"
  [1, 1.1, 0.8, 1.3]
  [2, 1.9, 2.2, 1.7]  3 rows in "N"
  [3, 3.1, 2.8, 3.3]


(1,N) matrix with actual values of N


  [1]
  [2]   Actual value of each sample N, in a single column
  [3]
```

So again, for clarity's sake, I'm looking to calculate the lstsq regression between each column of the (N,M) matrix and the (1,N) matrix.

For instance, the regression between

```
[1]   and [1]
[2]       [2]
[3]       [3]
```

then the regression between

```
[1]   and  [1.1]
[2]        [1.9]
[3]        [3.1]
```

and so on, outputting the slope, intercept, and standard error (average residual) for each regression calculated.

So far in the numpy/scipy documentation and around the 'net, I've only found examples computing one column at a time. I had thought numpy had the capability to compute regressions on each column in a set with the standard

```
np.linalg.lstsq(arrayA,arrayB)
```

But that returns the error

```
ValueError: array dimensions must agree except for d_0
```

Do I need to split the columns into their own arrays, then compute one at a time? 
Is there a parameter or matrix operation I need to use to have numpy calculate the regressions on each column independently?

I feel like it should be simpler? I've looked it all over, and I can't seem to find anyone doing something similar.

Comment: You say your matrices are (N,M) (1,N). Lstsq expects (N, M) and (N), did you try using the transpose of arrayB? I get a slightly different exception from you though (LinAlgError: Incompatible dimensions), I'm using Python2.7, with numpy1.6

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you switched A and b?

Following works for me:

```
A=np.random.rand(4)+np.arange(3)[:,None]
# A is now a (3,4) array
b=np.arange(3)
np.linalg.lstsq(A,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

The 0th dimension of arrayB must be the same as the 0th dimension of arrayA (ref: the official documentation of  [np.linalg.lstsq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html)). You need matrices with dimensions `(N, M) and (N, 1)` or `(N, M) and (N)` instead of the `(N,M) and (1,N)` matrices you're using now.

Note that the `(N, 1)` and `N` dimensional matrices will give identical results -- but the shapes of the arrays will be different.

I get a slightly different exception from you, but that may be due to different versions (I am using Python 2.7, Numpy 1.6 on Windows):

```
>>> A = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
>>> b = np.arange(3).reshape(1, 3)

>>> np.linalg.lstsq(A,b)
# This gives "LinAlgError: Incompatible dimensions" exception

>>> np.linalg.lstsq(A,b.T)
# This works, note that I am using the transpose of b here
```